# 406 Not Acceptable error in Restcall

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am using ajax and spring.i am creating dynamic dropdown in my code.upto controller i am getting my dropdown.now i am creating a one ajax call to display dynaic values on my dropdown.when a make a ajax call i am getting **406 Not Acceptable error**

This is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#adropdownDetails").change(function() {
            var value = $('#adropdownDetails:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'envi',
                data : {
                   selectedaname :$('#adropdownDetails:selected').text()
                },
                success : function() {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

This is my ajax call.
This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public @ResponseBody List<Environments> getEnvironmentNames(@RequestParam String selectedaname ) throws SQLException {
        List<org.mvc.domain.Environments> environmentnamesList = loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
        System.out.println("envi size"+environmentnamesList.size());
        return environmentnamesList;
    }
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Format! This reference may help....http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2014 ....later, thanks for formatting!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a space in between:

```
$('#adropdownDetails :selected').text()
```

---

`$('#adropdownDetails:selected').text()` This might not be the value you are looking for. This is a `whitespace` or a new line character. you can check the snippet below:

```js
var selval = $('select:selected').text();
$('pre').html('<p>'+selval+'</p>');
```

```css
p{border:solid 1px grey; padding:2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select><option>select...</option></select>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: `$('#adropdownDetails :selected')` this is targeting the selected option text while without any space it could be the outerHTML of the select with options.